# Convert multiple List items inside a POJO to a new List in Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, arraylist

I have a POJO populated with a list of items in a Controller (after a rest ajax submit). This is the structure of the model that is populated:

```
public class AllNamesDto {

 private List<Long> id;
 private List<String> firstName;
 private List<String> LastName;
 private List<Boolean> manualSubmit;
 private List<String> program;

 //getters setters
}
```

I would like to extract all the list items from the model above and store them individually into a model List, e.g. the following model:

```
public class AllNamesDtoList {

 private long id;
 private String firstName;
 private String LastName;
 private Boolean manualSubmit;
 private String program;

 //getters setters
}
```

So something like

```
List<AllNamesDtoList> allNamesDtoList = new ArrayList<>();
allNameDtoList.add(AllNamesDto.items);
```

I know the syntax isn't correct, just ruffing it in to show quickly what I am trying to accomplish. My goal is to create a proper list of items (since I couldn't figure out a way to send a LIST through ajax properly, just a sublist of items in one POJO) to iterate over and save to the db.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You need to at least try something. You need a loop. At eas iteration, you need to get the element of each list at the current index, create an instance of  AllNamesDtoList (which is not a list at all, and should probably be named Person or something like that).

Comment: does all the list in `AllNamesDto` are of same length?

Comment: @Deadpool All the items in `AllNamesDto` would the same length. Each record is a "row" in a form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that in the lists the order is correct and they are all the same size:

First put a constructor with fields:

```
public AllNamesDtoList(long id, String firstName, String lastName, Boolean manualSubmit, String program) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
        this.manualSubmit = manualSubmit;
        this.program = program;
    }
```

And then we take the size of one of the lists and create an IntStream to iterate on the indices

```
List<AllNamesDtoList> allNamesDtoList = new ArrayList<>();

IntStream.range(0, id.size()).forEach(index -> allNamesDtoList.add(new AllNamesDtoList(id.get(index), firstName.get(index), LastName.get(index), manualSubmit.get(index), program.get(index))));
```

and the allNamesDtoList list would be full.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I'm giving it a try now. I'm not sure what you mean by `ids.size())` in your example and as soon as I get to `id.get(index)`, I hit an error. It doesn't know what I'm referencing.

Comment: I'm sorry I put ids, I wanted to put id, I just take one of your lists and look at its size. I've edited that part id.size(), it's like I've put firstName.size()

Comment: When I do this id.get(index), firstName.get(index)... are the AllNamesDto lists. @SiriusBits

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. For `ids.size()`. It will only work if I use `AllNamesDto.getId.size()` though.

But it's still not finding `id.get(index)`?

Comment: id.get(index), firstName.get(index)....is AllNamesDto.getId.get(index), AllNamesDto.getFirstName.get(index)...

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick! :)

With Collections, or iterators is there ANY way of shortening this that comes to mind? I will probably need to add about 10 more fields.

And I worry about error checking/exceptions, or null values (which will be the case but that's ok/valid.

But again, really appreciate the help!

Comment: Shoot, I just added a new List item in AllNamesDto, and if it's NULL, I have an exception thrown. Damn. :(

Comment: This proposed way is clean, but if you want to check nulls or control exceptions, the construction of the AllNamesDtoList can be used a separate method, and check the nulls. new AllNamesDtoList( methodCheckNullBeforeInsert(index))

Comment: Do you mean in the constructor or when creating the new list?

Comment: You can put it both in the constructor, for example instead of `this.id = id` do `if(id!=null) this.id = id`,
as in a method that makes allNamesDtoList.add... and passes the index to it and checks nulls for each item in the list.